# Insert into table B from another table A if entry does not exist

Tags: mysql

i want insert in table "filtre" the last 100 records (ORDER BY TIME DESC 
LIMIT 0 , 100) of table "call_record"  When entry does not exist.
the problem is that it insert row even this row exist.so i have duplicate row in the filtre

```
INSERT INTO filtre (number, sim_name, duration, time)
SELECT number, sim_name, duration, TIME
FROM `call_record`
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT number, sim_name, duration, time
  FROM filtre 
) 
AND 
sim_name =1701
GROUP BY number
ORDER BY TIME DESC 
LIMIT 0 , 100
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the GROUP BY clause here?

Comment: Add a unique index and INSERT IGNORE without checking if the data already exists

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are not correlating the rows in the subquery with the parent query. Your subquery just checks if ANY row exists in 'call_record'. Try this:

```
INSERT INTO filtre (number, sim_name, duration, TIME) 
SELECT number, sim_name, duration, TIME 
  FROM call_record cr
 WHERE NOT EXISTS ( 
       SELECT 1
         FROM filtre f
        WHERE cr.number = f.number
          AND cr.sim_name = f.sim_name
          AND cr.time = f.time
          AND cr.duration = f.duration) 
   AND sim_name =1701 
 GROUP BY number 
 ORDER BY TIME DESC LIMIT 0 , 100
```

This wouldn't be the most efficient way to achieve the desired outcome though off-hand. I'm puzzled by your GROUP BY clause though so am not sure what to suggest without a better understanding of the dataset you are dealing with.

Alternatively, as symcbean suggests in the comments above, adding a unique index on your table and using INSERT IGNORE should solve the problem. It is common practise to add an Id column with an auto-incrementing integer value and just set that as a primary key. Assuming you only insert and never update records, this should work for you. You won't need a unique index across all columns that way.

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO filtre (id, number, sim_name, duration, TIME) 
SELECT id, number, sim_name, duration, TIME 
  FROM call_record
 WHERE sim_name = 1701 
 ORDER BY TIME DESC 
 LIMIT 0 , 100
```

Comment: i just try it,  it add even row exist

Comment: GROUP BY is to avoid to have duplicate row when SELECT * FROM call record

Comment: Using a GROUP BY on a subset of the selected columns where some or all other selected values are not aggregate functions that can give a single result per 'group' is something peculiar that MySQL allows while other databases typically would not. The result is somewhat unpredictable though. I'm not convinced it is adding any value in this instance - try without it and see if this makes a difference.

Comment: Again, without understanding the nature of the data in the tables (eg. what duplicates you might be expecting in call_record, what the intended purpose of the filtre table is etc.), it is difficult to provide more useful guidance.

Comment: can you test:   http://41.242.35.252/phpmyadmin/    root /60503652   database = scheduler

Comment: You should add the 'id' column to your filtre table as a primary key, but not set it to be auto-incrementing since you will always be inserting explicit values for it in that table, then try the alternate query provided above. (And PLEASE change your password immediately! You are screaming for the world to hijack your system by providing root credentials here.)